# Firebase notifications received only after relaunching app

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have setup Firebase using Firebase assistant in Android Studio. I am facing one small, but irritating issue. The notifications doesn't work on first launch, but working on all subsequent launches. e.g.

- App-installed and opened for first time: Notifications are not received.
- If I force-stop the app and restart: Notifications are working now.

I suspect that subscription request is not working on first request. 
following is my token refresh code in android FirebaseInstanceIdService:

```
 @Override
 public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if(refreshedToken != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("news"); 
            sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
        }
    }
```

I do get the registration token in first launch and it is sent to server successfully. But the notification is received only after restarting the app. 
Any ideas why it is not working in first launch?

Edited code as suggested in comments. I have saved new token to sharedPrefs and called the Subscription function from activity. BUT THIS IS STILL NOT WORKING. App getting notification only after relaunching the app.

```
 @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
       String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
       if(refreshedToken != null){
            Log.d("FCGM", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
            myPrefs settings = new myPrefs(); //my class to handle prefs, working fine
            settings.putBool("isNewToken",true);
            settings.putString("token",refreshedToken);
        }
    }
```

then, in my activity onCreate function, i called the subscription function after a 5 sec delay to make sure that the token is generated and saved.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    myPrefs settings = new myPrefs();
    if (settings.getBool("isNewToken")){
        Log.d(TAG,"new token found");  //this is reaching 
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("news");
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
        settings.putBool("isNewToken",false);
    }
  }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your topic subscription into your Application subclass or your main activity, the code to subscribe to the topic looks after sending the correct token in the call.

Also by only having the subscription call in onTokenRefresh() what would happen if your user unsubscribed from the topic at a later stage? They wouldn't be able to re-subscribe at a later point.

Comment: i have saved the token to sharedPrefs and called the topic subscription from activity but the app is still getting notifications only from second launch onwards.

Comment: Can you show your current code now for subscribing? Exclude anything sensitive from the code.

Comment: Why are you unsubscribing at the same time? I don't know for certain, but the calls to subscribe and unsubscribe could finish at different times if they are async calls. Also there should be no need to delay by 5 seconds, the call to subscribe looks after making sure the token is sent when subscribing. It also has a retry mechanism built in to retry the request if it fails.

Comment: as per google docs one need to re-subscribe on new token. so i tried unsubscribing it before renewing the subscription. i will try without unsubscribe it as there could be a race condition. The delay was required as token takes some time to generate and i wanted to make sure we have it before subscribing. If i dont put a delay the subscription code is called before app could get a new token.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the issue was GET request in my sendToken function, which was not finishing off. It should have been a POST method. I have now changed it and is working perfectly. my current onTokenRefresh code is:

```
 @Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    if(refreshedToken != null){
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("news");
        sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
        myPrefs settings = new myPrefs();
        settings.putBool("isNewToken",true);
        settings.putString("token",refreshedToken);
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
        Log.d(TAG, "Subscribed");
    }
}
```

the send token code looks like this now:

```
 client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 client.setRequestMethod("POST");
 client.setDoOutput(true);
 OutputStream outputPost = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
 outputPost.write(params.getBytes());
 outputPost.flush();
 outputPost.close();
```

Hope it helps someone with similar issue.